# Accesing arraylist property from another class using constructor

Tags: arraylist, constructor

So i have a class that makes an array list for me and i need to access it in another class through a constructor but i don't know what to put into the constructor because all my methods in that class are just for manipulating that list. im either getting a null pointer exception or a out of bounds exception. ive tried just leaving the constructor empty but that dosent seem to help. thanks in advance. i would show you code but my professor is very strict on academic dishonesty so i cant sorry if that makes it hard.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't make it hard; rather, it makes it *completely impossible* to help you.  You could at least attempt to sketch the problem in a way that could allow others to help you.

Comment: If you're not going to show what you've tried because you're afraid your professor will disapprove, you don't have a very good teacher. On the other hand, if you are truly expected to solve this on your own, you shouldn't be asking here. How can we even provide answers?

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing the main question, with a potential solution.

Main Question:

```
I have a class ArrayListOwnerClass with an enclosed arraylist property or field.
How should another class ArrayListFriendClass access that property.
```

Potential Solution:

```
Should I pass the arraylist from ArrayListOwnerClass to ArrayListFriendClass,
in the ArrayListFriendClass constructor ?
```

It depends on what the second class does with the arraylist.

Instead of passing the list thru the constructor, you may add functions to read or change, as public, the elements of the hidden internal arraylist.

Note: You did not specify a programming language. I'll use C#, altought Java, C++, or similar O.O.P. could be used, instead.

```
public class ArrayListOwnerClass
{
  protected int F_Length;
  protected ArrayList F_List;

  public ArrayListOwnerClass(int ALength)
  {
     this.F_Length = ALength;
     this.F_List   = new ArrayList(ALength);
     // ...
  } // ArrayListOwnerClass(...)

  public int Length()
  {
    return this.F_Length;
  } // int Length(...)

  public object getAt(int AIndex)
  {
    return this.F_List[AIndex];
  } // object getAt(...)

  public void setAt(int AIndex, object AValue)
  {
    this.F_List[AIndex] = AValue;
  } // void setAt(...)

  public void DoOtherStuff()
  {
    // ...
  } // void DoOtherStuff(...)

  // ...

} // class ArrayListOwnerClass

public class ArrayListFriendClass
{
  public void UseArrayList(ArrayListOwnerClass AListOwner)
  {
    bool CanContinue =
      (AListOwner != null) && (AListOwner.Length() > 0);
    if (CanContinue)
    {
      int AItem = AListOwner.getAt(5);
      DoSomethingWith(Item);
    } // if (CanContinue)
  } // void UseArrayList(...)

  public void AlsoDoesOtherStuff()
  {
    // ...
  } // void AlsoDoesOtherStuff(...)

  // ...

} // class ArrayListFriendClass
```

Note, that I could use an indexed property.

Comment: thank you i know my question was cryptic in wording, but your answer helped me to realize multiple things that should allow me to implement it.